# How to Validate Single Item in a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, partial-views

I have a Model that is shaped like this:

```
public class GlobalSettingsViewModel
{
   public List<SettingViewModel> Settings{ get;set;}
}

public class SettingViewModel 
{
   public string Name{ get;set;}
   [Range(0,100)]
   public decimal SettingValue{ get;set;}
}
```

My view calls `Html.RenderPartial("SettingView")` for each SettingViewModel.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SettingViewModel>" %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "GlobalSettings", FormMethod.Post))
   { %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="150px">
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Name) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.SettingValue) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="uiButton" />
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SettingValue) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
   <%} %>
```

Each `SettingView` renders a form which posts back to a Save action.

The `SettingViewModel` is correctly rehydrated from the form and the validation correctly determines when an out or range value is generated.

I returned the original `Index` view with the full `GlobalSettingsViewModel` it requires.

However, when the page renders **every** Validator for SettingValue shows it's error message instead of just the textbox with the incorrect value?

What is the correct way for performing server side validation on a `PartialView` when it is page of a collection of items?

---

### UPDATE

So here's what I have....it seems a little odd but seems to work..

I can save a single setting at a time and show validation errors when they occur.  But the weird way in which I save by using a partial model seems a little odd.

Index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/MVC.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<GlobalSettingsViewModel>" %>
<fieldset style="margin: 5px; width: 350px;">
        <legend>Global System Settings</legend>
        <div>
            <%= Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Settings)%>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

SettingViewModel.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SettingViewModel>" %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "GlobalSettings", FormMethod.Post))
   { %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="150px">
            <%= Model.Name %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SettingValue) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="uiButton" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SettingValue) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SettingName)%>
<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)%>

<%} %>
```

GlobalSettingsController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var settings = GetSettings();

            if (TempData["Message"] != null)
            {
                settings.Message = TempData["Message"].ToString();
                settings.HasMessage = true;
            }

            return View(settings);
        }

        [AuthorizationFilter(true, null)]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(GlobalSettingsViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                GlobalSettings.SetGlobalSetting(model.Settings[0].SettingName, model.Settings[0].SettingValue);
                TempData["Message"] = "Saved " + model.Settings[0].Name;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var settings = GetSettings();

            return View("Index", settings);            
    }
```

Comment: I've set Mystere Man's answer as correct as it does not require the use of AJAX requests and sticks to the Post/Redirect/Get pattern.

However, Darin's answer is 100% just as effect, possibly better in terms of performance as there is no need to reload all the settings.

Comment: Actually, after leaving this project for a while and coming back this solution only works for the first setting, all others return `model.Settings` as `null`

Comment: Looking at the the Request.Form collection the model is being loaded as settings[x].SettingName etc, where x is the index.  So settings[0] works find but settings[1] doesn't load.

I don't understand why this is so hard to do, I _must_ be doing something wrong!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use AJAX so that you don't have to refresh the entire page. So your Save action will return the partial passing it only the current setting:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(SettingViewModel model)
{
    // TODO: do some processing
    return PartialView("SettingView", model);
}
```

then wrap the forms in some div container so that we can more easily know which section to update when the AJAX call succeeds:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Settings) { %>
    <div class="setting">
        <%= Html.Partial("SettingView", item) %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

and finally AJAXify those forms in some separate javascript file:

```
$(function () {
    $('.setting').delegate('form', 'submit', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            context: this,
            success: function (result) {
                $(this).closest('.setting').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do I redirect to when the save takes place?  

`return PartialView("SettingView", model);` As well?

Comment: @MattC, return a Json with the url you want to redirect to: `return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("Success") });` and then inside the AJAX success callback: `if (result.redirectTo) { window.location.href = result.redirectTo; } else { $(this).closest('.setting').html(result); }`.

Comment: Thanks, this technique worked...but is this how MVC is supposed to be used...seems a lot of fiddling just to do what webforms easily did with a gridview and no more testable, custom json and ajax flying about? Given a list of values it shouldn't be this awkward to update a single value/row?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that RenderPartial generates the same ID's for each SettingsViewModel.  If you look at your rendered code, you'll notice duplicate ID's in the page, and that's not valid HTML.

You might do better to use an EditorTemplate for SettingsViewModel, and that will have the logic necessary to create unique ID's.

Comment: I've created a Template in
Views -> Shared -> EditorTemplates -> SettingViewModel.ascx
And then instead of looping I did; `<%Html.EditorFor(m => m.Settings); %>` but nothing is rendered at all?

Comment: Forget that forgot `<%=`.  So I've changed my Save action to look like this:

'public ActionResult Save(GlobalSettingsViewModel model)' which correctly brings back the full model and my main view now has only one form.

But how do I know which submit button was clicked?

Comment: @MattC - You would still create the form for each setting, then post to an action method that takes a single SettingsViewModel, not the list.

Comment: So I presume that if my `ModelState` is `Invalid` then I return `View("Index", [GlobalSettingsViewModel])` so it can render the validation messages?

Comment: Also when I post to an action taking `SettingsViewModel` all the model properties are `null.  All the inputs are rendering as `name="setting.SettingValue"`